# Show that $0$ is a limit point of $[-1,2)$

Tags: real-analysis

> Show that $0$ is a limit point of $[-1,2)$

Our aim is to show that for all nbd $N(0,\epsilon)$, $$N'(0,\epsilon)\cap[-1,2)\neq \phi$$
where $N'(0,\epsilon)=(-\infty,-\epsilon]\cup[ \epsilon, \infty)$ is the deleted nbd of $N(0,\epsilon)=(-\epsilon, \epsilon)$.

i.e we have to show that $\exists z\in N'(0,\epsilon)\cap[-1,2)$

> Please help me to find such z.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have you tried sketching those intervals over the real line?

Comment: I find N′(0,ϵ)=[−1,−ϵ]∪[ϵ,2)  and N(0,ϵ)=(−ϵ,ϵ)

Comment: Why is that? Do you remember that the radius $\epsilon$ may be as small as one want it to be? You need to show that, no matter how small the radius $\epsilon$ is, as long as it's $>0$, there will be an element $z$ that belong both in $N'(0,\epsilon)$ and in $[-1,2)$. How can you find this element $z$?

Comment: Yes  I want to find z such that $z\in N'(0,\epsilon)\cap[-1,2)$ and I explore  N′(0,ϵ)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take $$\frac12\min(\epsilon,1).$$

Comment: ok. it is good choice if $\epsilon>1$. I understand. But $N′(0,ϵ)=(−\infty,−ϵ]∪[ϵ,\infty)$ correct? then how $ z=\frac12\min(\epsilon,1)\in N′(0,ϵ)$, rather $z\in N(0,\epsilon)$

Comment: please help me to understand

Comment: @user1942348: as you have now understood, your definiton of $N'$ was wrong.

Comment: Yes, the definition was wrong and that crests many confusions.

Answer (score 1):

We have $N'(0,\epsilon)=(- \epsilon, \epsilon) \setminus \{0\}$ !

Let $t= \epsilon/2$ , then $t  \in N'(0,\epsilon)$.

Comment: I am unable to understand that  $\epsilon/2 \in N'(0,\epsilon)$

Comment: $N′(0,ϵ)=(−\infty,−ϵ]∪[ϵ,\infty)$ correct?

Comment: If $N(0,\epsilon)=(-\epsilon, \epsilon)$, then $N'(0,\epsilon)=(-\epsilon, \epsilon) \setminus \{0\}$. Since $0<\epsilon/2 < \epsilon$ we have $\epsilon/2 \in N'(0,\epsilon)$.

Answer (score 1):

You have the wrong definition of the deleted neighborhood $N'(0,\epsilon)$. The correct definition is

$$N'(0,\epsilon)=(-\epsilon,0)\cup(0,\epsilon)$$

With this definition, Yves Daoust's answer does the trick.

The set you defined, $(-\infty,-\epsilon]\cup[\epsilon,\infty)$, is the *complement* of the neighborhood $N(0,\epsilon)=(-\epsilon,\epsilon)$.

Comment: Ohh Yes, thanks a lot

Comment: @user1942348, glad to help. Like Fred and Yves (I think), I at first saw the words "deleted nbd" and didn't look carefully at your formula for $N'$ because I know what a deleted neighborhood is supposed to be.